# LIKE statement, MySql

Tags: php, mysql

I have some PHP that looks like this:

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM $userName WHERE day LIKE "%1%"';
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0)  {

#do stuff 2

} else {

#do stuff 1

}
```

What is wrong with my SELECT statement? $userName defines the table the script should look for, day is a column and the LIKE statement searches for the letter '1' in every row of that column. If it finds a row with '1' in it, it should execute

```
#do stuff 2
```

However, it always executes

```
#do stuff 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `$sql='SELECT * FROM $userName WHERE day LIKE "%1%"';` instead of this use `$sql="SELECT * FROM $userName WHERE day LIKE '%1%'";`-------see quotes

Comment: Thanks - it works! Why does the switch in quotation marks make the difference? @MASIDDIQUI

Comment: `$name = "meraj"; echo '$name';` // prints $name,`echo "$name";` //prints meraj

Comment: If you're creating a separate table for each user, you likely have bigger problems than can be addressed here.